# Include records based on another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have table with "incidents" a second table with "notes/calls" and a third table with "assets".

I am trying to include ONLY records from the first table which are NOT referenced in the second or third...

As I write this another thought comes to mind... in any case suggestions are appreciated.

This is where I currently am...

```
    SELECT tblCustIncidents.EntryDateTime, tblCustIncidents.IncidentID, tblCustIncidents.LocID
    FROM tblCustIncidents
    WHERE (tblCustIncidents.IncidentID Not In (SELECT  tblCustCalls.IncidentID 
    FROM tblCustCalls) OR tblCustIncidents.IncidentID Not In (SELECT  tblIncidentAssets.IncidentID 
    FROM tblIncidentAssets)) AND  (tblCustIncidents.EntryDateTime)>Date()-17;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL it would be something like

```
select * from incidents where incident_id_column not in 
(select incident_id_column from notes/calls union select incident_id_column from assets)
```

Not sure how access does it

hope that helps though

Comment: that's kind of where I think I m thanks for commenting... not sure if I have parens wrong...

Comment: Here is a different flavor if you want to try it:

Comment: Here is a different flavor if you want to try it:
SELECT CI.EntryDateTime, CI.IncidentID, CI.LocID, tblIncidentAssets.IncidentID, tblCustCalls.IncidentID
FROM (tblCustIncidents as CI LEFT JOIN tblIncidentAssets ON CI.IncidentID = tblIncidentAssets.IncidentID) LEFT JOIN tblCustCalls ON CI.IncidentID = tblCustCalls.IncidentID
WHERE (((CI.EntryDateTime)>Date()-17) AND ((tblIncidentAssets.IncidentID) Is Null) AND ((tblCustCalls.IncidentID) Is Null)) OR (((CI.EntryDateTime)>Date()-17) AND ((tblIncidentAssets.IncidentID) Is Null) AND ((tblCustCalls.IncidentID) Is Null));